# Porque mi algoritmo me devuelve el espacio en memoria en vez del valor que necesito

Tags: java, array

Quiero hacer que me imprima los dos arreglos juntos, porque cuando me imprime, me imprime los espacios de memoria en vez del contenido del arreglo.

Lo que me piden es: Presente el código de una rutina que reciba dos arreglos de enteros y retorne un nuevo arreglo, que incluya los números del primer arreglo y del segundo arreglo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arreglosDobles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de números que desea ingresar para el primer arreglo:");
        int tamanoA = 0;
        tamanoA = entrada.nextInt();
        int numerosA[] = new int[tamanoA];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanoA; i++) {
            System.out.print("Digite un numero para el primer arreglo: ");
            numerosA[i] = entrada.nextInt();

        }
        {
            System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de números que desea ingresar para el segundo arreglo:");
            int tamanoB = 0;
            tamanoB = entrada.nextInt();
            int numerosB[] = new int[tamanoB];

            for (int k = 0; k < tamanoB; k++) {
                System.out.print("Digite un numero para el segundo arreglo: ");
                numerosB[k] = entrada.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Los elementos del ambos arreglos son:");
            for (int i : numerosA);
            for (int k : numerosB);
            System.out.println(numerosA.toString());
            System.out.println(numerosB.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas imprimiendo de forma incorrecta el contenido arreglo, es decir, lo que estás haciendo hasta ahora es imprimir el arreglo completo, lo que devuelve el espacio ocupado en memoria del mismo:

```
for (int i : numerosA);//Recorres el arreglo A sin hacer nada
for (int k : numerosB);//Recorres el arreglo B sin hacer nada
System.out.println(numerosA.toString());//Esto imprime el espacio de memoria 
//que ocupa el arreglo completo
System.out.println(numerosB.toString());//Esto imprime el espacio de memoria 
//que ocupa el arreglo completo
```

---

Lo correcto sería imprimir mientras se recorre cada arreglo, de esta manera imprime uno por uno todos los elementos que contiene el arreglo en cuestión:

```
 for (int i : numerosA){//Recorre el primer arreglo
     System.out.println(i); //Imprime uno por uno los elementos del arreglo A
 };
 for (int k : numerosB){ // Recorre el segundo arreglo
     System.out.println(k);//Imprime uno por uno los elementos del arreglo B
 };
```

Comment: Gracias Riaven! Aunque or alguna forma extraña me sigue tirando la posición

Comment: :O bastante raro, probé este código en mi IDE, y ha funcionado correctamente, me ha devuelto los números correspondientes

Comment: Tal vez es que no sé utilizar muy bien mi IDE, pero me alegra saber que si funciona, lo dejaré como me enseñaste, gracias!

Comment: Procura solo poner el índice System.out.println(i); /porque si pones numerosA, saldrá de todas maneras el espacio en memoria, si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, márcala como aceptada, en el tic en la parte izquierda de la misma :)

Comment: Gracias, ya lo logré y acepté tu respuesta. Millones de gracias

Comment: Hola ;) me alegro de haber sido de ayuda para ti, debajo del puntaje de la pregunta al lado izquierdo hay un símbolo check ✓,  este acepta la respuesta como aceptada ;)

Comment: Ah ya lo logré, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas el método `Arrays.toString(array)` de la clase `Arrays`.

También te puse el método que retorna una nueva lista:

```
package pruebaarrays;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaArrays {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        int tamanoA = 0;
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de números que desea ingresar para el primer arreglo:");
        tamanoA = entrada.nextInt();

        int numerosA[] = new int[tamanoA];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanoA; i++) {
            System.out.print("Digite un numero para el primer arreglo: ");
            numerosA[i] = entrada.nextInt();

        }
        int tamanoB = 0;
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de números que desea ingresar para el segundo arreglo:");
        tamanoB = entrada.nextInt();
        int numerosB[] = new int[tamanoB];

        for (int k = 0; k < tamanoB; k++) {
            System.out.print("Digite un numero para el segundo arreglo: ");
            numerosB[k] = entrada.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Los elementos de ambos arreglos son:");
        //Arrays.toString(arreglo) es el método que necesitabas para visualizar los
        //elementos del array sin tener que iterar
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(CrearyRetornarNuevaLista(numerosA , numerosB)));
    }
    //esta es la rutina que te piden. Está declarado estático para poder llamarlo
    //desde el método main
    public static int[] CrearyRetornarNuevaLista(int[] a, int[] b){
        int listaAB[] = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int longitListaAB =listaAB.length;
        int longitA =a.length;
        int longitB =b.length;
        int posicA =0;
        int posicB =0;

        for (posicA = 0; posicA < longitA; posicA++) {
            listaAB[posicA] =a[posicA];
        }
        for (posicB = posicA; posicB < longitListaAB; posicB++) {
            listaAB[posicB] =b[posicB - posicA];
        }
        return listaAB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Juan, no he visto este método aún y me parece súper interesante!

Comment: De nada. No olvides marcar mi respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió. Un saludo!

Comment: ¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: en cada respuesta, arriba a la izquierda, hay un `spinner` (flecha arriba y flecha abajo para incrementar o decrementar), este `spinner` es para que cualquier persona de la comunidad (con 15 o más puntos de reputación), dé su voto. Pero además, el que formula la pregunta, en este caso vos, puede marcar la respuesta como `aceptada` haciendo clik un poco más abajo del `spinner`, donde se encuentra un `check` (tilde), el cual después de dar clik cambia al color verde